# Can mitmdump be used to capture HTTPS and store sessions in HAR or SAZ (Fiddler) files?

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm looking for a command-line capable alternative to Fiddler for Linux.

I'm advising a customer who is using a Linux version of our product, and we need them to provide a decrypted capture of the HTTPS traffic from a service.  I'm very familiar with Windows and Fiddler but not enough with Linux or Mitmproxy.

Can captures made with mitmdump be saved as either HAR or SAZ files?

I don't have access to the private keys on the other side of the communications, so Wireshark isn't an option.

Thanks!
Bill

Comment: Why don't you just record the session using mitmproxy? Python and mitmproxy (in detail mitmdump and mitmweb) run fine on Windows. BTW: For extracting the pre-master secrets for Wireshark you only need control on on the server or the client. A lot of clients can be configured to record the pre-master secrets.

Comment: We only have access to the Linux system via an SSH session, so we don't have the UI for mitmproxy.  However, getting the pre-master secrets on the client might be the route we'll need to go.